Virtual machine scale set and agent pool in Devops
I created the Agent pool using my VMSS at one of my customer.
Today customer complained the jobs are queued for so long and never runs. I went to check and I see this error:

We are unable to connect to your virtual machine scale set. Please go
to the pool settings tab and verify your Azure Subscription settings.

I went to settings to see more details and to try to edit the Agent pool which is created by my user but I have this error:

VS30063: You are not authorized to access
https://management.azure.com.

What is the issue? Im not sure if customer has removed some specific permissions from but I cant trouble shoot much. any ideas what could go wrong here? I still can access their Subscripion and RG tho.
